# Django Make Migration Error No Such Column

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a pre-existing model that I am now trying to add an additional field too. It wasn't me that made the original field but I have been adding fields to other classes and making migrations fine.

I want to add an additional image field to the class Event, there is already an image field on this class so I know it can handle image fields, I have tried changing the name around to see if that was a issue too. Here is the field I want to add:

```
social_media_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='Hello World')
```

This is the error I get when i'm trying to make my migration after adding that code to the model:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: posts_event.social_media_image
```

From my understanding of how migrations work there shouldn't be a column called this yet as I haven't made the migration yet that will add it to the DB.

I have tried adding a default value to the field as well but with no luck. I have also tried completely removing the DB along with migration files and trying to recreate them.

Here are the rest of the fields in the model:

```
slug = AutoSlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, populate_from='title')
content = models.TextField(default='')
start_time = models.DateTimeField()
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, help_text=image_help_text)
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: posts_event.social_media_image

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/source/enfield_presents/posts/apps.py", line 37, in ready
    search.register(Event.objects.get_upcoming_events(site_id=settings.SITE_ID, include_spektrix=False, return_queryset=True))
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/source/enfield_presents/posts/models.py", line 282, in get_upcoming_events
    events_with_a_next_start_time = [e for e in events if e.next_start_time() is not None]
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: posts_event.social_media_image
```

Comment: Can you show some more of the model?

Comment: what command are you running after adding the field?

Comment: Your Image filed is missing `upload_to=upload_location`. Just saying. So just to get this clear you run `./manage.py makemigrations` and then `./manage.py migrate` right? And you don't have to remove the DB completely. Next time do a Rollback https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182633/django-migration-dependencies-reference-nonexistent-parent-node/44182969#44182969

Comment: Show all model fields and have you written any forms for this model ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the other models in this class. @hansTheFranz I run makemigrations and get that error. Seeing as making the migration fails running migrate won't have any effect

Comment: This usually happens when you execute queries on import. Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: @knbk Yeah absolutely here it is https://pastebin.com/qh8wB8s3

Comment: Please don't use third-party websites for this, but [edit] your post to include the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be due to the reason that the corresponding Image field may not be present in the database. Please login to the database shell and check whether the corresponding field is there. If it is not there add it manually using SQL query or rollback to a previous safe migration and then make the changes in models.py and generate the migration files.

Answer (score 0):

It's right there:

```
File "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/enfield/enfield-presents/source/enfield_presents/posts/apps.py", line 37, in ready:
search.register(Event.objects.get_upcoming_events(site_id=settings.SITE_ID, include_spektrix=False, return_queryset=True))
```

You do a queryset on the source of one app, that as far as I can tell, queries the model of the other app. You shouldn't do queries in app setup if you can avoid it. Use signals if you have to or lazy loading.

If you really have to, then flip the order of the apps. If it's the same app, then yes, don't do it: as you notice, you won't be able to do any migrations.